# Database Design - functional dependency methodology

Tags: database-design, methodology, functional-dependencies

Is there any standard methodology (step-by-step system) to determine the functional dependencies of a database? Maybe an algorithm that i could apply?I'm trying to optimize a beta database model i have created for a site like imdb and to work through Armstrong's axioms seems impossible for a huge database model, like the one i have created.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you're a new user, I should warn you that this question is attracting [close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) under the following reason: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: If we think the Intersubjective objectivity everything can be minded as subjective/or opitionated.What i am asking here is not someone to go and search for me, but if there is such a thing as a standard methodology for functional dependencies (that would be a fact not an opinion), or has any good resource to share about this topic(facts), since i haven't found anything like it so far. Please if there is a specific site rule i'm violating explicitly refer to it (since i don't seem to fit into the "close votes" category).Thanks for the advice though

Comment: I think you've misunderstood. Your question has 2 close votes so far. If it gets 3 more (or 1 from users with a certain rep), it will be closed. You can edit your question before or after it's closed to make it seem less like you're seeking a recommendation for a tutorial or library, especially the part wherey ou ask about "videos, books, blogs, etc."

Comment: Thanks Two-Bit Alchemist. Where can i see the close votes of my post?

Comment: You don't have the rep to do so yet (which is why I told you in a comment).

Comment: thanks! Is my current post legit?

Comment: Short answer: no. It is possible to create two *different* valid models to model the same data. There is no ultimate "canonical" model for a given set of data. Semantics: it is genearlly impossible to derive a model given only sample data. You'll need the *intended* data on which you want to impose a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functional dependencies are really business rules, i.e. statements about the real world to be modelled in a database. There is no tool or shortcut that can decide them for you. You have to discover functional dependencies through proper analysis and understanding of the problem domain.